# How to crawl external web search

Tags: c#, web, web-crawler, robots.txt

I have a website, http://www.op.nysed.gov/opsearches.htm, for example where the user selects a **Profession** and enters a **Licensee Name** and clicks on the **Search** button which takes them to a new page to display the result.

For example, the following:

[image]

Which displays the following result:

[image]

Clicking on any of the set of number next to each name brings up the information, in example like this:

[image]

I looked at scrapy, arachnode and other web crawlers on the web for this purpose but wasn't too convinced that is the right technology for it.

I was told that we have to crawl those search results from the page. Is it something that can be done?

Can crawler crawl as the user does the search?

Comment: Where are you supposed to get that data from, all the internet?? If that's the case then that search can take months to complete...

Comment: Ok, I think I got the point, you want to "steal" that info from the page, right?

Comment: Yes, pretty much steal the data :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Crawling programs will get you a local copy of the target web's srtucture, not really sure if that is what you want.

If you want to extract that data and store it in a way you can query it later, then you must create your own app.

As a point of start the idea is this:

Navigate manually through the web and analyze the POST's done between pages (as an example, what is sent to the server when "Architect" is selected and the button is pressed, or where points a link on the license) and find the real queries, which variables are sent and the formatt of them, then analyze the page's HTML structure to find patterns which can be used with a regular expression engine.

That part will be a hard, you must analyze outgoing and incoming HTTP queries (LiveHTTP Headers complement in Firefox can help you a lot) to simulate them in your program, and construct realiable regular expressions patterns (to test regular expressions [The RegEx Coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/) comes very handy).

Once you know how to navigate through the page structure and have patterns to strip the data, the rest is relatively easy, create a client using WebClient, navigate through the structure, strip the necessary data and store it in a DB.

As you can see this is a very broad answer, but because your question also is really broad.

Comment: I was able to get the query to give me the direct response: `http://www.nysed.gov/coms/op001/opsc2a?profcd=08&plicno=001363&namechk=AND` How would I go on about creating a web client?